# How to download everything in that folder using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to download all the csv files that exist in s3 folder(2021-02-15). I tried the following, but it failed. How can I do it?

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')
key = 'product/myproject/2021-02-15/'
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
for obj in objs:
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.download_file(bucket, obj, obj)
```

`valueError: Filename must be a string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marcin answer is correct but files with the same name in different paths would be overwritten.
You can avoid that by replicating the folder structure of the S3 bucket locally.

```
import boto3
import os
from pathlib import Path

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')

key = 'product/myproject/2021-02-15/'
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))

for obj in objs:
    # print(obj.key)

    # remove the file name from the object key
    obj_path = os.path.dirname(obj.key)

    # create nested directory structure
    Path(obj_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # save file with full path locally
    bucket.download_file(obj.key, obj.key)
```

Comment: It’s really convenient to check the folder structure thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `resource`, youu can use [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_file):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')

key = 'product/myproject/2021-02-15/'
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))

for obj in objs:
    #print(obj.key)
    out_name = obj.key.split('/')[-1]
    bucket.download_file(obj.key, out_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`cloudpathlib`](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/) which, for S3, wraps `boto3`. For your use case, it's pretty simple:

```py
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath

cp = CloudPath("s3://bucket/product/myproject/2021-02-15/")
cp.download_to("local_folder")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Filter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/collections.html#filtering) returns a collection object and not just name whereas the [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html#downloading-files) method is expecting the object name:

Try this:

```
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
client = boto3.client('s3')
for obj in objs:
    client.download_file(bucket, obj.name, obj.name)
```

You could also use `print(obj)` to print the `obj` object in the loop to see what it actually has.

Comment: There's no need to instantiate a `client` for every object. Just move the third line outside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just took changes from the question but thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Marcello, I found I had to perform a check to see if the item I was downloading was a `file` or a `"directory"` from s3. I adjusted the method slightly to also download the items from s3 into a specified folder locally.

```
    download_directory = './download_directory'  # replace with your root directory
    bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket') # replace with your bucket
    objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder')) # replace with your s3 'folder'

    for obj in objs:
        if obj.key.endswith('/'):
            continue # if the obj is a folder / directory then skip it

        obj_path = os.path.dirname(obj.key)
        local_file_path = os.path.join(download_directory, obj.key)

        Path(os.path.dirname(local_file_path)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, local_file_path)
```